# How to install a windows 7 disk with Ubuntu 13.04 in a uefi computer?

Tags: dual-boot

I used the entire disk to install ubuntu.Now I want to install windows 7.What should I do so that I dont have to do anything to my ubuntu data.I have plenty of free space.(window's Os doesn't show up in my dell inspira4tion 14r laptop at the uefi options in the boot menu pressing F2.)My ubuntu OS is 64 bit uefi.

Answer (score 0):

I think backup data,DELETE EVERYTHING, (don't use uefi, for me (i thing for most users it's a little confusing)) install windows, then ubuntu. Best choice... Try some GRUB tools anyway... try partedmagic liveCD With this you can try to resize (do smaller) your partition (of course it need to have some free space.) (backup even with this choice, just in case if something went wrong...) GOOD LUCK! Sorry if my english is confusing!

Comment: I was thinking about that too. I will do that. But are u suggesting me to boot both windows 7 and ubuntu in legacy mood?

Comment: Windows 7 DVD will install in BIOS mode. You would have to convert from DVD to flash and make some updates to have it work with UEFI. If converting to BIOS you have to also convert from gpt partitioning to MBR(msdos) partitioning which will erase entire drive. There are some tools that may let you convert. http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html